# How to set-up Jenkins ext email reports to send only failed tests from build (without those who have passed)?

Tags: jenkins

I'm working with Junit/Ant .I wrote this script in Default contents, but it sends me a report with passed and failed tests, and I'd want it to be the only with a failed tests.

Jenkins Report!


**Configuration :**

Project Name : $PROJECT_NAME

Project URL : $PROJECT_URL
 
Build number: #$BUILD_NUMBER

Job Description: $JOB_DESCRIPTION


**Execution Results :**

Status : $BUILD_STATUS

Run: ${TEST_COUNTS}, Failed: ${TEST_COUNTS,var="fail"}, Passed: ${TEST_COUNTS,var="pass"}, Skipped: ${TEST_COUNTS,var="skip"} 


Report preview :

Answer (score 0):

hi you can create email template and configure the email-ext step like below:

```
emailext body: '''${SCRIPT, template="groovy-html.template"}''', 
            subject: "${env.JOB_NAME} - Build # ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} - Successful", 
            mimeType: 'text/html',to: "to list"
```

here the groovy-html.template is the default template which jenkins pickup and render the result in that template. You can edit [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/groovy-html.template) email template to have only failed tests and save that template in the $JENKINS_HOME/email-templates directory and use this template.

Note : use different name for the template other than groovy-html.template.